# Draw a check mark CSS animation from left down to right up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to draw a check mark from the left going down to the right going up with CSS animations. I got the left going down part, but going back up doesn't seem to working. It goes from right to down. Does anyone know how I can make this smoother and actually look like a check being drawn?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#kick').addClass('draw2');
}, 500);
```

```css
#kick {
  height: 150px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: -24px;
  left: 273px;
}
#stem {
  height: 60px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes draw1 {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 60px
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes draw2 {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 150px;
  }
}
.draw1 {
  -webkit-animation-name: draw1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
.draw2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: draw2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="checkmark">
    <div class="draw1" id="stem"></div>
    <div id="kick"></div>
</span>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help in getting this animation right! Also, since I'm using jQuery anyway, if this can be done more efficiently in jQuery/JavaScript, that's fine too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, this is my approach using `<canvas>` and JavaScript.

### Demo on Fiddle -----> [Square Corners](http://jsfiddle.net/1faqu4yt/) | [Round Corners](http://jsfiddle.net/9ffeL8rb/)

(**Note:** To change the animation speed increment or decrement the variable `animationSpeed`. Lower number yeilds Higher speed)

```js
var start = 100;
var mid = 145;
var end = 250;
var width = 20;
var leftX = start;
var leftY = start;
var rightX = mid - (width / 2.7);
var rightY = mid + (width / 2.7);
var animationSpeed = 20;

var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = width;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)';

for (i = start; i < mid; i++) {
  var drawLeft = window.setTimeout(function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(start, start);
    ctx.lineTo(leftX, leftY);
    ctx.stroke();
    leftX++;
    leftY++;
  }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
}

for (i = mid; i < end; i++) {
  var drawRight = window.setTimeout(function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(leftX, leftY);
    ctx.lineTo(rightX, rightY);
    ctx.stroke();
    rightX++;
    rightY--;
  }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
}
```

```html
<canvas height="160"></canvas>
```

---

You could also do this using `svg` and CSS `animation`.

**1. Square Corners:**

```css
#check {
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-dasharray: 180;
  stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  -webkit-animation: draw 2s infinite ease;
  animation: draw 2s infinite ease;
}
-webkit-@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <path id="check" d="M10,30 l30,50 l95,-70" />
</svg>
```

---

**2. Round Corners:**

```css
#check {
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 180;
  stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  animation: draw 2s infinite ease;
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <path id="check" d="M10,50 l25,40 l95,-70" />
</svg>
```

Comment: How do you make the animation once draw once and stay on the screen? For the SVG examples @chipChocolate.py

Comment: @JennyC Oops sorry I missed that question, @Jonathan is correct, remove `infinite` from the `animation` and `-webkit-animation`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, easy to implement, thank you!!

Comment: This works cool in firefox and chrome.But not working in IE9.Do you have a workaround for ie

Comment: @Master.Deep you need to set the animation-play-state property to 'forward' to make it stay on the screen: `animation` and `-webkit-animation` should be set to `draw 2s ease forwards`

Answer (score 6):

I wanted a checkmark that looked like the material [done icon](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=done&style=round), so I adjusted the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26560472/5560171) a little. Posting it here in case it saves someone a bit of time.

```css
.animated-check {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
}

.animated-check path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: 23;
  stroke-dashoffset: 23;
  animation: draw 1s linear forwards;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="animated-check" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M4.1 12.7L9 17.6 20.3 6.3" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```